# How to move on from first function to the next one?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, return

I've been learning and practicing JavaScript on my own by reading books and practicing what I've learnt. I'm a little stuck on how to get something working and would like your guys help.

```
        function guessAge(){
            var userInput = parseInt(prompt("Guess my age!", 100),10);

            if(userInput == 25){
                alert("Correct!");
            }else{
                alert("Incorrect");
            }

            return guessAge();
        }

        function guessMovie(){
            var input = prompt("Guess my favourite movie!");

            if(input == "Lego"){
                alert("Everything is awesome!");
            }else{
                alert("Incorrect!");
            }
        }

        guessAge(); //Initialise guessAge function
        guessMovie(); //Initialise guessMovie function
```

I wanted to get the first function to repeat if the answer was wrong but continue to the next one if it was correct but return seems to keep repeating regardless if it's correct or incorrect.

Comment: Hint: When the answer is correct, do you want to call `guessAge()` again? No, but you recursively call it no matter what answer is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return after the correct guess. This way you're first method will stop calling itself

```
function guessAge(){
        var userInput = parseInt(prompt("Guess my age!", 100),10);

        if(userInput == 25){
            alert("Correct!");
            return;
        }else{
            alert("Incorrect");
        }

        return guessAge();
    }
```

Alternatively, you can put the recursive call to the method within the else block. That way it will only be called when you have had an incorrect guess.

```
function guessAge(){
        var userInput = parseInt(prompt("Guess my age!", 100),10);

        if(userInput == 25){
            alert("Correct!");
        }else{
            alert("Incorrect");
            return guessAge();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Rubber duck debugging](http://www.rubberduckdebugging.com/) is a good way to find logic errors. The stuff in comments is what you would say aloud to a rubber duck while stepping through your code line by line.

```
function guessAge() {
  /*
    I'm asking the user for input with a default value of 100
    I'm then parsing a string to an integer that is base 10
    I store the result in userInput
  */
  var userInput = parseInt(prompt("Guess my age!", 100), 10);
  /*I check if the user input is 25 */
  if (userInput == 25) {
  /* The user input is 25 so I alert that they are correct */
    alert("Correct!");
  } else {
  /* otherwise I alert that they are incorrect */
    alert("Incorrect");
  }

  /*I return what guessAge returns. Right now there is no other 
    return statements out of the function so I will always call
    this line */
  return guessAge();
}
```

After the first pass step through again but this time say what you want to do.

```
function guessAge() {
  /*
    I want the user input to see if they can guess my age
  */
  var userInput = parseInt(prompt("Guess my age!", 100), 10);
  /*I check if the user input is 25 */
  if (userInput == 25) {
  /* The user input is 25 so I alert that they are correct */
    alert("Correct!");
  /* I want to leave the function guessAge after the user guesses
     correctly. */
  } else {
  /* otherwise I alert that they are incorrect */
    alert("Incorrect");
  /* I want to call guessAge again since the user guessed wrong */
  }

  /* this statement is out of my control flow block so it will always
     be reached, even if the user entered the correct age. I want to 
     leave the function when the user enters the correct answer but
     this line will allways call guessAge */
  return guessAge();
}
```

From there you can try out some solutions. Remember there are multiple ways to solve a problem.

```
function guessAge() {
  var userInput = parseInt(prompt("Guess my age!", 100), 10);
  if (userInput == 25) {
    alert("Correct!");
  /* I want to leave the function guessAge after the user guesses
     correctly. if I do nothing after my else we will leave the 
     function without having to do anything */
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect");
  /* I want to call guessAge again since the user guessed wrong */
    guessAge();
  }
}
```

Note that you don't have to return anything from a function. Nor do you have to always return when calling a function. You use return when you want to return a value back to the function caller.